# Can I get Recharts lines to work like Plotly lines?

Tags: javascript, recharts, fable-f#

I have data that looks like this

```
[
{
ReadingName:"humidity",
ReadingDate:\someDate,
ReadingValue: 55
},
{
ReadingName:"temperature",
ReadingDate:\someDate,
ReadingValue: 30
}, ...
]
```

I want the user to be able to select elements to chart based on whatever reading names are in the data. The list of names is not known at design time.

In plotly I can simply specify a new `trace` for each line, and each `trace` I specify a value to filter on. So trace 1 can be all reading values where reading name equals "Humid" etc. The key thing is I only need one type of data.

But in Recharts, I need to create a data structure with each line as a separate column. Then when I add lines, I specify which line maps to which column. This is fine if your lines/columns are known at design time, but it gets trickier when you only discover the lines/columns at run time.

Is there a way for me to use Recharts, with a single generic data structure as above, similar to how Plotly takes data?

Comment: Why not just filter the data on the value of `ReadingName` that the user has selected?